# Как в Yandex mapkit отключить вращение карты вокруг маркера позиции?

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

Искал на всех доступных форумах ответ, не нашел, придется спрашивать тут!
В моем приложении с Yandex mapkit, пользователь стоит на месте, а карта периодически  вращается вокруг центра экрана, где расположена метка текущей позиции. Как сделать так, что бы карта не вращалась, а, например, вращался стрелка маркера позиции пользователя?
Спасибо!

[image: Вот как это выглядит в приложении]

[image: Сразу через секунду]

Comment: А вы спрашивали в поддержке Яндекса? То, что вы желаете реализовать - коммерческий сценарий: "Нельзя использовать API для мониторинга и диспетчеризации". А раз так, то очевидно, что подобными проектами занимаются не бесплатно и делиться информацией просто так не будут. Если у вас уже оплачена коммерческая лицензия, поддержка должна подсказать.

Comment: Проект бесплатный, никакой диспетчеризации нет в проекте, пользователь видит себя на карте и все. На сайте поддержки, насколько я понял, или часто задаваемые вопросы или спрашивайте на stackooverflow

Comment: Если пользователь видит себя на карте постоянно (а вращение карты именно об этом и говорит), а не меткой при разовом запросе, то это отслеживания местоположения в реальном времени, что является нарушением шестого условия бесплатного использования. Перечитайте: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/commercial/doc/concepts/about-enterprise.html А поддержка вполне в состоянии подсказать по методам из документации, пусть порой и с уточнением у разработчиков. Но если вам нужна инфа о коммерческом сценарии, будьте добры предъявить оплаченную лицензию - это вроде как разумно.

Comment: на сколько я понимаю, пользователь отслеживает сам себя и он никаким образом не является "мобильным сотрудником" В бесплатной версии API запрещается использовать карту в следующих целях:
    для отслеживания местоположения транспорта или мобильных сотрудников в реальном времени;

Comment: Тем не менее, в лицензии есть и другие ограничения, например, я хочу в дальнейшем регистрировать пользователей, которые препятствуют развитию приложения и я принял решение отказаться от яндекс карт, развернуть свой сервер OpenMapStreet и перейти на osmdroid

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Answer (score 0):

```
userLocationLayer.setHeadingEnabled(false);
```

true - вращается карта, false - вращается стрелочка!

Вписать сразу после `userLocationLayer.setVisible(true);`